# SQLAlchemy Engine Fails to Fetch Records from Specific Oracle EBS Table but Talend Open Studio Succeeds

Tags: oracle, sqlalchemy, cx-oracle

I'm facing an issue with a specific scenario involving an Oracle EBS database. I'm attempting to fetch records from a table named `ap_lookup_codes` using SQLAlchemy in Python. However, the SQLAlchemy engine fails to retrieve any records from this table and produiung no error, despite successfully fetching records from other tables in the same database.

```python
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker

# Replace the connection string with your actual database connection details
engine = create_engine('oracle+cx_oracle://user:password@host:port/dbname')
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session = Session()
    
results = session.execute("SELECT * FROM ap_lookup_codes").fetchall()
print(results)
```

Interestingly, when I execute a similar data fetching operation in Talend Open Studio, it successfully retrieves the records from the `ap_lookup_codes` table. This discrepancy suggests that the issue might be specific to how SQLAlchemy interacts with this table.

What could be the possible reasons for SQLAlchemy's failure to fetch records from the `ap_lookup_codes` table, especially considering that Talend Open Studio can fetch the records successfully? Are there any known limitations or configurations in SQLAlchemy when dealing with Oracle EBS databases that might cause this behavior?

Comment: Please [edit] the question and include a [MRE] with: the `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT` statement for your sample data; and the error messages from your procedure. Stating "the SQLAlchemy engine fails to retrieve any records from this table" is not a constructive statement as it does not tell us whether the query works and does not return any rows or does not work and raises an exception nor what that exception is.

Comment: From a vanilla SQLAlchemy perspective, there is no reason why records should not be retrieved assuming that the engine is pointing to the correct database / schema. The most common cause of this kind of issue is that the expected rows have been committed to the database _after_ the SQLAlchemy transaction has begun.

Answer (score 0):

Un`COMMIT`ted data is only visible within the session that created it (and will `ROLLBACK` at the end of the session if it has not been `COMMIT`ted). If you can't see the data from another session (i.e. in SQLAlchemy) then make sure you have issued a `COMMIT` command in the SQL client where you `INSERT`ed the data (i.e.  Talend Open Studio).

*Note: even if you connect as the same user, this will create a separate session and you will not be able to see the uncommitted data in the other session.*

From the [`COMMIT` documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/COMMIT.html#GUID-6CD5C9A7-54B9-4FA2-BA3C-D6B4492B9EE2):

> Until you commit a transaction:
>
> - You can see any changes you have made during the transaction by querying the modified tables, but other users cannot see the changes. After you commit the transaction, the changes are visible to other users' statements that execute after the commit.
> - You can roll back (undo) any changes made during the transaction with the `ROLLBACK` statement (see `ROLLBACK`).

---

If the data is committed then:

1. Make sure you are connecting to the correct database instance.
2. Make sure you are connecting to the correct user.
3. Make sure that the user you are connecting to has permissions to see the data if they are not the owner.
4. Make sure that you are querying the correct table.

   Note: Oracle is case-sensitive but, in many cases, will abstract that away from the user by converting unquoted identifiers to upper-case so:

   ```sql
   SELECT * FROM ap_lookup_codes
   ```

   is identical to any of:

   ```sql
   SELECT * FROM AP_LOOKUP_CODES
   SELECT * FROM Ap_Lookup_Codes
   SELECT * FROM Ap_LoOkUp_CoDeS
   SELECT * FROM "AP_LOOKUP_CODES"
   ```

   but:

   ```sql
   SELECT * FROM "ap_lookup_codes"
   ```

   would be querying a different table. If your table name is actually lower-case then you will need to use a quoted identifier. You may find that you have two tables one is lower-case and contains data and one is the same name but upper-case and contains no data (and that would one reason why using quoted identifiers is not considered good practice as you can get into the situation where you have multiple tables differing only be the case used in their names and it causes confusion).

Comment: data is already commited in source database, if this is the case the talend open studio should not retrieve data

Comment: @OwaisAjaz Updated with other options.

Comment: i changed the language in sql developer preference and now showing data there but still no row return in sqlalchemy engine.. is there any nls language tuning needed?

Comment: Thanks @MT0 for the help, i have resolved the issue.. the issue was with NLS_LANG parameter in on env.

Answer (score 0):

while reading data from oracle db using sqlalchemy NLS_LANG was creating the issue. please note this is on level configurations, we can edit in regedit

```
SQL> select * from NLS_DATABASE_PARAMETERS;
Output: NLS_CHARACTERSET    US7ASCII
```

then i configure in python db connection manager

```
`os.environ["NLS_LANG"] = "AMERICAN_AMERICA.US7ASCII"`
```